# How do I change a cell value in an ASP.NET GridView based upon another cell value when the update button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to change a cell value in a `GridView` when a user edits another cell value in that `GridView`. Here is the `RowUpdating` function that I have tried:

```
Private Sub Gv_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles Gv.RowUpdating
        Dim Gvr As GridViewRow = DirectCast(sender.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim lessonName As String = Gvr.Cells(2).Text
        Gvr.Cells(3).Text = GetLessonID(lessonName)
    End Sub
```

As you can see, I tried casting the naming container of the sender to a `GridViewRow`, but that doesn't work. I thought the naming container would be the `GridView` itself, but it is not. Basically, I need to know how to access the cell that needs to be automatically changed in the `RowUpdating` function. I should mention that the cell in question cannot be edited by the user; rather, it is updated automatically when the `Update` button is clicked. Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leverage the [RowIndex Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.rowindex(v=vs.110).aspx) from the GridViewUpdateEventArgs parameter and access the grid directly:

```
gv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Text = grv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says: "'Rows' is not a member of 'GridViewRow'." This is what I tried: Gvr.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Text = GetLessonID(lessonName). This is using `Gvr` as it is defined above. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Sorry about that, updated to gv.  The point is to access the GridView directly and then leverage the RowIndex from the event arguments to access the correct row.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! I will try it.